# opencart 3.0.2.0 remove model required restriction

Tags: opencart

How can i remove the "model required" from the model field in admin product page in opencart v 3.0.2.0, and make it an optional field like the rest of the fields in the data tab?
[model required screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8XmZr.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its not correct to not insert model no, still i show you.

**admin\controller\catalog\product.php**

go to line no 1193  - approximate

find this code in **protected function validateForm() {**

```
if ((utf8_strlen($this->request->post['model']) < 1) || (utf8_strlen($this->request->post['model']) > 64)) {
            $this->error['model'] = $this->language->get('error_model');
        }
```

after comment

```
/*if ((utf8_strlen($this->request->post['model']) < 1) || (utf8_strlen($this->request->post['model']) > 64)) {
                $this->error['model'] = $this->language->get('error_model');
            } */
```

you have to comment this code or you can remove it, but i think you need this code in future so do only comment this code don't remove it.

Comment: Thanks Sainent I commented the code you suggested but it did not help and model is still required.

Comment: which opencart version you are using.?

Comment: using v 3.0.2.0